# Error (1005) when trying to create foreign key

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a basic foreign constraint, however I'm getting a syntax error. `#1005 - Can't create table 'my_database'.'#sql-334f_952bc' (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")`

I first create the tables and then use the 'alter table' method to create the foreign constraint.

Creating tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_flights` (
  `flight_id`      int(11)       NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  `aircraft_id`    int(11)       NOT NULL
  `date`           date          NOT NULL
  `auth_by`        varchar(255)  NOT NULL
  `auth_duration`  time          NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`flight_id`)
)
;

CREATE TABLE `tbl_aircraft` (
  `aircraft_id`    int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  `registration`   char(6) NOT NULL
  `insurance`      date    NOT NULL
  `awrc`           date    NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`aircraft_id`) 
)
;
```

Creating foreign key/constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl_aircraft` 
ADD CONSTRAINT  `fk_aircraft_id` FOREIGN KEY ( `aircraft_id` ) 
REFERENCES `my_database`.`tbl_flights` ( `aircraft_id` ) 
ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE ;
```

If anyone could identify the issue here I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

base in the error message 
could be you missed  the ; at the end of the statement

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_flights` (
  `flight_id`      int(11)       NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  `aircraft_id`    int(11)       NOT NULL
  `date`           date          NOT NULL
  `auth_by`        varchar(255)  NOT NULL
  `auth_duration`  time          NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`flight_id`)
)
; /* add this */

CREATE TABLE `tbl_aircraft` (
  `aircraft_id`    int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  `registration`   char(6) NOT NULL
  `insurance`      date    NOT NULL
  `awrc`           date    NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`aircraft_id`) 
)
; /* add this*/
```

could be you have inverted  the tables

```
 ALTER TABLE `tbl_flights` 
 ADD CONSTRAINT  `fk_aircraft_id` FOREIGN KEY ( `aircraft_id` ) 
 REFERENCES `my_database`.`tbl_aircraft` ( `aircraft_id` ) 
 ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE ;
```

or you must add a foreign column in TABLE `tbl_aircraft`

Comment: Thank you, I added the `;` and am now getting a different error: errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Comment: well this mean  that your error message in solved .. +

Comment: I have update the answer  with a suggestion  .. anyway change the question after recived a right answer  is not  fair  .. you should rate this answer and eventually post a secodnd question ..